# UK Visitor visa extension

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I had a query related to UK visitor visa extension.
My mother in law got UK visitor visa from 5th April to 4th October 2019. 
She traveled to UK on 6th April and traveled back to India on 18th May (she stayed in UK for 44 days)
Now she again traveled back on 1st July and her planned return date is 3rd Oct (95 days planned stay). So her overall stay is four and half months in UK.

Reason for her travelling now and extension is - currently my wife is expecting and her delivery date is 23rd September.
So, my mother in law wants to extend her stay for around 2 months.

Is it possible? If yes then please suggest the procedure.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-visa

Comment: @Traveller It can be an answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

From the Immigration Rules Appendix V https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

> How long can a visitor extend their stay in the UK
>
> V 8.7 A visitor (standard) and a visitor for marriage or civil partnership, who was granted a visit visa or leave to enter for less than 6 months may be granted an extension of stay as a visitor so that the total period they can remain in the UK (including both the original grant and the extension of stay) does not exceed 6 months.

If your mother-in-law’s current planned stay means she will have spent 4.5 months in the UK, she can apply to stay for up to a further 1.5 months.

The application must be submitted online and whilst she is in the UK. The fee is £993 plus £19.20 to provide biometrics https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-visa